# What is a good data structure and file format for describing road network geometry AND topology?

Tags: road, file-formats, geometric-network, connectivity-analysis

I am trying to emulate the road network from OSM or Google (or Waze, etc.) locally, so that I can run some algorithms on it.

For that, I want to represent these roads as graphs, where each edge would be a linestring, each node would be a point, and each point, etc.

Is there already a good file format for that, preferrably text-based? (JSON or CSV would be great). I have already seen some formats, such as STL, which stores geometries as indexed points, and describe the topology only by referencing these points. As such, an intersection would refer the same point from each of its incoming or outgoing roads, for example.

I am not a GIS professional, only an interested programmer, so I would prefer simplicity and light-weight-ness if possible. I don't mind devising my own custom "format" if I get to understand what type and structure of information I would be supposed to be representing in the first place.